# Restrict RDP access via Username but Allowed via Computer

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2016, remote-desktop, rdp

Can anyone help me with my configuration? So I need to configure RDP access restrictions for certain users and machines. I've managed to do this by creating a GPO rule on Allow log on through Terminal Services and  only apply access to certain groups. But here's the catch, for those users that don't have access, they will need to go to a Jumpserver and from there, they should have access to login using their account only by using that jump server.

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Your users should be able to access the server, but your users should not be able to access the server? That makes no sense for business environments. As computers are not authenticated in RDP, this will be hard to do, too.

Comment: Maybe windows firewall rules (wf.msc) are what you're looking for to restrict access only from an authorized IP? Connection security rules can even be used to restrict access to members of a security group.